# How to fix "signatures do not match previously installed version" error?

Tags: installation, signature-error

I'm using a Moto G6. With the latest update to android 9, they removed the capability of using the built-in Dolby Audio equalizer for some stupid reason.

I found this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/MotoG/comments/b9ahmh/cant_turn_off_dolby_audio_on_g6_after_update_to/el4nebr?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) that had a way to modify the APK to make this work. I followed all the steps. I decided to try the 20 band equalizer steps and made a backup of the previous work before starting. However, when I finally got to the ADB install DaxUI2.apk, it didn't work. I got this error:

> adb: failed to install DaxUI2.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.dolby.dax2appUI signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!]

This was saddening, but no biggie, right? Because I already had a backup. I renamed the DaxUI2 folder to DaxUI2broken, renamed my backup to DaxUI2, and I tried again, with just the first part (minus the appendix). Once I did this, though, I got the exact same error.

I'd like to be able to fix this, so if anyone knows how, please tell me!

Comment: I made sure I had removed com.dolby.dax2appUI though. I ran pm list packages | grep dolby, and I had just com.dolby.daxservice. I can post a screenshot if needed.

Comment: here is the link:https://imgur.com/a/5G84ZUU

Answer (score 2):

just uninstall the current app and then run it again.

Answer (score 1):

connect device to PC. Turn USB Debugging on
Execute these command

```
adb shell
pm list packages|grep <Package Name>
```

You'll get a package name for it which would look like `com.xyz.example`

`adb shell pm uninstall <package name>`

Comment: those days adb has unstall cmd: `adb uninstall <package name> `